# Set limite on recyclerview items

Tags: android

I have item lists in recyclerview
And i want to limite it just by 2 items to

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout android:id="@id/root_swipe_refresh" android:background="@color/grey_5c6773" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView android:id="@id/scroll_container" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:fillViewport="true">
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@id/orders_list" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="520.0dip" />
```

Nb: i cant edit the java file , i can just edit this xml file

So i want  to edit here and which code i add

Answer (score 0):

`@Override public int getItemCount() { return 2; }`

Comment: Where i add it ?

Comment: You can add this in recyclerview adapter.